# Making/Initializing Array of Struct Like Objects in Java

Tags: java, c, arrays

I am using Java SE on NetBeans 7.3.1.

I would like to form a Java array similar to the following in C

```
typedef struct sNewStruct{
    int min;
    int max;
} NewStruct;

NewStruct nsVar[19];
```

I tried the following

```
class IntRange{
    int min, max;    
}
IntRange[]  rangeNodes = new IntRange[19];
```

My problem is that, while rangeNodes is successfully allocated, all of its elements are nulls.

Comment: Loop over it and assign `new IntRange()` to every single one of them.

Comment: why would you think it should contain anything, you never set them to anything?

Comment: You can't really do the stack based allocation that C allows.  It's unfortunate coming from C/C++, but that's how Java is.  There are answers that show you what you must do.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson He would think that because that is how structs work in C/C++, an idea that has no analogue in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is how it should behave. Java isn't going to guess that the array should be filled with elements instantiated with the zero-argument constructor. If you want to fill the array, all you need to add is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rangeNodes.length; i++)
    rangeNodes[i] = new IntRange();
```

You could explicitly initialize each element, but this is the cleanest solution.

Comment: @JoshM Gotta be faster! :P

Comment: I was changing songs, will not happen again :)

Answer (score 2):

As @ccKep is suggesting, you must assign a value to each element in the array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rangeNodes.length; i++)
    rangeNodes[i] = new IntRange();
```